# Trigger after Insert value from another table

Tags: c#, mysql, triggers

I have two tables Employee and Employee Log, I created a trigger after insert, I have no problem with my after insert trigger using entities or values from employee, to insert directly to Log table, but how would I insert value from another table? like Admin_ID. I want a log table with transaction, datetime and who created.

Thank you.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER emp_log_af AFTER INSERT ON emp

  FOR EACH ROW

   BEGIN

     INSERT INTO emp_log (action,id,ts, ad_id)

     VALUES('create',NEW.id,NOW());

   END;
```

Comment: What are you tried so far just give your code here?

Comment: the ad_id or admin_id is my problem im using C# my employee table does not contain admin_id or ad_id

Comment: Are you looking for `CURRENT_USER`? Or `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1) from dual` Pulled from [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,154460,154460)

Comment: Thank you yap current_user @TaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible with trigger what i did was get the max(id) to do that i created a stored procedure.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_user_log
 (
    IN ia Varchar(12), 
    IN ie INT, 
    IN ix datetime  
 )

  BEGIN
   DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 0;
      SELECT MAX(user_id) INTO id FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1;
   BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO `user_log`(`action`, `user_id`, `employee_id`, `ts`) VALUES (ia, id, ie, ix);       
    END; 

   END$$


   DELIMITER ;

   DELIMITER $$
```